# Proportional symbols map using Leaflet & jQuery isn't working

Tags: jquery, json, xmlhttprequest, leaflet

I am super new to this so sorry if this is super easy, but I am trying to make a proportional symbols map using Leaflet and JQuery, following this tutorial: https://neiugis.github.io/lab7/

Basically, I had my json saved as a local file, and my getJSON request looked like this:
         $.getJSON("CTHValue.geojson")

but I ran into an CORS error, so I decided to upload my json to an online host. Here is the link: https://api.myjson.com/bins/nh71g. However, my code still doesn't seem to work, the symbols are not showing up on my map, but I am not getting an error in the console. I need some help! My code is as follows:

```
    function addCTHValue() {

    $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/nh71g')
    .done(function(data) {
    });

    function processCTHValueData(data) {

    var min = Infinity;
    var max = -Infinity; 

    for (var feature in data.features) {
        var properties = data.features[feature].properties;

      for (var attribute in properties) {
          if ( attribute = 'CTH Value' )

          {
              if (properties[attribute] < min) {
                  min = properties[attribute];
              }
              if (properties[attribute] > max) {
                  max = properties[attribute];
              }
          }
      }
  }
  return {
      min : min,
      max : max
  }
}           
    function CTHValueSymbols(data) {

      CTHValueCountries = L.geoJson(data, {

          pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
              return L.circleMarker(latlng, { 
                  fillColor: "#501e65", 
                  color: '#501e65',      
                  weight: 2,             
                  fillOpacity: 0.5       
              }).on({
                    mouseover: function(e) {
                        this.openPopup();
                        this.setStyle({fillColor: 'green'});
                    },
                    mouseout: function(e) {
                        this.closePopup();
                        this.setStyle({fillColor: '#501e65'});
                    }
            });
          }
      }).addTo(map);
    }

    function calcCTHValueRadius(attributeValue) {

      var scaleFactor = 0.01; 
      var area = attributeValue * scaleFactor;

      return Math.sqrt(area/Math.PI);
    }

            $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/nh71g')
    .done(function(data) {
        var info = processCTHValueData(data);
        calcCTHValueRadius(info.data);
    });
}
```

Do I need to do a XMLHttpRequest or is citing the link sufficient? I wrote the following XMLHttpRequest, but tbh I don't know what I am supposed to do with this request, like, where in my code does it go? Am I supposed to replace the link in the $.getJSON request? What do I replace it with? Do I need to create a variable for the json which I can then cite in the $.getJSON request?

```
    let requestURL = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/nh71g';

    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', requestURL);

    request.responseType = 'json';

    request.send();
```

If anyone can spot what is wrong I'd really appreciate it. Please let me know about the XML request too, bc idk if that's what is causing my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgott to call the function to add the data to the map.

```
$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/nh71g').done(function(data) {
        var info = processCTHValueData(data); 
        CTHValueSymbols(data) //<---------
    });
```

Also you can get different sizes with this:

```
pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
              return L.circleMarker(latlng, { 
                  fillColor: "#501e65", 
                  color: '#501e65',      
                  weight: 2,             
                  fillOpacity: 0.5,
                  radius: feature.properties["CTH Value"]/100 //<-------
              }).on({
                    mouseover: function(e) {
                        this.openPopup();
                        this.setStyle({fillColor: 'green'});
                    },
                    mouseout: function(e) {
                        this.closePopup();
                        this.setStyle({fillColor: '#501e65'});
                    }
            });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/zrbLhwcp/

Comment: Thank you! The proportional symbols are still not showing on the map, though

Comment: Have you looked into my example?

Comment: Yes, but the console keeps saying that I have missing curly brackets when I don't :-( I checked and mine's the same as yours. Do you know how to fix this? I have recounted my brackets like 10 times and I can't see anything missing

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sophhGIS/8nadyhux/ 
ive never used jsfiddle before so sorry if ive done it wrong, on notepad++ my code still isnt creating proportional circles

Comment: Put your JS code into: https://beautifier.io/ then you see that at the end 2x } is missing. Also you have in the `pointToLayer` function between the `L.circleMarker([...])` creation and the `.on([...])` a `;` remove this. Don't forgett to check the answer ;)